# Is there a way to compare two variables in Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

```
[% IF OrgType.id == Organization.org_type_id %]selected="selected"[% END %]
```

Does not work even when they both evaluate to the same number.

```
[% IF OrgType.id == 3 %]selected="selected"[% END %]
```

(i.e. hard-coding in a number for testing purposes) does work.

```
[% OrgType.id %] and [% Organization.org_type_id %]
```

both print "3" on the page.

Comment: From the Perl side, ensure that they are exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
 my $tt = Template->new; 
 $tt->process( \"[% IF foo == bar %]blah[% END %]", { foo => 42, bar => 42 } );
```

That outputs 'blah'. So I suspect that your two variables don't contain what you think they do. Template Toolkit uses string equality for `==`, so if you do:

```
 my $tt = Template->new; 
 $tt->process( \"[% IF foo == bar %]blah[% END %]", { foo => 42, bar => "42 " } );
```

It will break. You may need to massage the data a bit to get them to work right with string equality.